# Getting a log of computers that have remotely accessed a Windows server

Tags: windows, ip, remote-desktop

I have suspicions that someone other than people on my team have obtained the credentials to remotely access a Windows 2008 Server. I need to get some evidence before I start pointing fingers or get everyone alerted that someone might be hacking our servers.

Can I get a log of all the computers that have remotely accessed my server (by remote access I mean using the remote desktop features of Windows server). Ideally there should be some information about each computer, at least their public IP address.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Is there a log file for RDP connections?](http://superuser.com/questions/409099/is-there-a-log-file-for-rdp-connections). Which service on the server do you want to check? I've only made a wild guess from the tag.

Comment: That link was helpful, I'll try it out. I am trying to look at RDP connections, but also any other type of access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once someone has access to your server it's not your server anymore. Meaning that logs could be tampered with as well as binaries.

There is a security log in Windows which allows you (if configured correctly) to:

- Account logon events
- Account management
- Directory service access
- Logon events
- Object access
- Policy change
- Privilege use
- Process tracking
- System events

There is just a catch here. Any administrator will be able (as mentioned before) to tamper with the logs. If you are unsure it is best to place a sniffer between your server and the network. That way you can monitor all incoming and outgoing connections and determine if the IPs accessing the machine are indeed legitimate.